# Perl - count words of a file

Tags: linux, perl

i want to count words in a file and want result the number of same word

my script

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

#use strict;
#use warnings;

use POSIX qw(strftime);
$datestring = strftime "%Y-%m-%d", localtime;

print $datestring;

my @files = <'/mnt/SESSIONS$datestring*'>;
my $latest;

foreach my $file (@files) {
  $latest = $file if $file gt $latest;
}

@temp_arr=split('/',$latest);

open(FILE,"<$latest");
print "file loaded \n";
my @lines=<FILE>;
close(FILE);

#my @temp_line;

foreach my $line(@lines) {

    @line=split(' ',$line);
    #push(@temp_arr);

    $line =~ s/\bNT AUTHORITY\\SYSTEM\b/NT__AUTHORITY\\SYSTEM/ig;   

    print $line;

    #print "$line[0] $line[1] $line[2] $line[3] $line[4] $line[5] \n";

}
```

My log file

```
SID        USER                      TERMINAL        PROGRAM
---------- ------------------------- --------------- -------------------------
         1 SYSTEM                    titi            toto (fifi)
         2 SYSTEM                    titi            toto (fofo)
         4 SYSTEM                    titi            toto (bobo)
         5 NT_AUTHORITY\SYSTEM       titi            roro
         6 NT_AUTHORITY\SYSTEM       titi            gaga
         7 SYSTEM                    titi            gogo (fifi)

         5 rows selected.
```

I want result :

```
User = 3 SYSTEM with program toto
, User = 1 SYSTEM with program gogo
```

Thanks for any information

Comment: Please [edit] your post and tell us what the program currently does and where you are having problems fixing that.

Comment: i don't know how to begin

Comment: This is not a programming teaching site. Most likely you want to learn about hashes and how to use them for counting. You already split the input into columns, and now you want to count the occurrence of items of the second column.

Comment: ... also, you don't want to "compare", you want to "count"

Comment: ok, do you have an idea for delete two first line in the array ?

Comment: Yes - in your loop, when you see that the line starts with `SID` or starts with `---`, skip all processing (`next`). Or maybe skip all processing until you have seen a line that consists only of `---...--`. http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/next.html

Comment: Also, why do you comment out `use strict;` and `use warnings;` ? These two pragmata are here to help you.

Comment: i don't know to use the function next

Comment: Yes - that's why I also showed you the link to the definition of the `next` keyword in Perl. This site is not about teaching Perl or about teaching how to program, so I cannot really help you with either here.

Comment: i put this line $line =~ s/\bNT AUTHORITY\\SYSTEM\b/NT__AUTHORITY\\SYSTEM/ig; in the top and now after the next that not work

Comment: Why did you add this line and what do you expect it to do? Programming is about having a plan and then describing that plan to the computer. I don't see the plan in what you are doing here.

Comment: i added this line because in the log i have NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM, and i translated to NT__AUTHORITY\SYSTEM, and now the translation don't work

Comment: You should get a clear idea of: input, expected output, and then read up on how to achieve that. I can't even see your statement of what you expect from your script making sense, how do you expect to produce working code that way?

Comment: i saw, that's work

Comment: now i want to count but not doesn't work  if ( $line[1] && $line[3] == $line[1+$d] && $line[3+$d] ) {
 
 $i = $i+1;
 $d = $d+1; 
  
 print "$line[1] $line[3] = $i \n";
 
 }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see yours as a two-step problem -- you want to parse the log files, but then you also want to store elements of that data into a data structure that you can use to count.

This is a guess, based on your sample data, but if your data is fixed-width, one way you can parse that into the fields is to use `unpack`.  I think `substr` might more efficient, so consider how many files you need to parse and how long each is.

I would store the data into a hash and then dereference it after the files have all been read.

```
my %counts;

open my $IN, '<', 'logfile.txt' or die;
while (<$IN>) {
  next if length ($_) < 51;
  my ($sid, $user, $terminal, $program) = unpack 'A9 @11 A25 @37 A15 @53 A25', $_;

  next if $sid eq '---------';  # you need some way to filter out bogus or header rows

  $program =~ s/\(.+//;         # based on your example, turn toto (fifi) into toto

  $counts{$user}{$program}++;
}
close $IN;

while (my ($user, $ref) = each %counts) {
  while (my ($program, $count) = each %$ref) {
    print "User = $count $user with program $program\n";
  }
}
```

Output from program:

```
User = 3 SYSTEM with program toto
User = 1 SYSTEM with program gogo
User = 1 NT_AUTHORITY\SYSTEM with program roro
User = 1 NT_AUTHORITY\SYSTEM with program gaga
```

Comment: hello, thanks, i don't understand if length ($_) < 51;

Comment: It's a prefilter for the log file lines you don't care about (for example "5 rows selected,") but more importantly if you don't include it short lines will cause the `unpack` statement on the next line to break.  In essence, if the line doesn't have enough data to list a "program," then skip.

Answer (score 0):

This code detect automatically the size of input fields (your snippet seems an output from Oracle query) and print the results:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use v5.10;

open my $file, '<', 'input.log' or die "$?";

my $data = {};
my @cols_size = ();

while (<$file>) {

    my $line = $_;

    if ( $line =~ /--/) {
        foreach (split(/\s/, $line)) {
            push(@cols_size, length($_) +1);
        }
        next;
    }

    next unless (@cols_size);
    next     if ($line =~ /rows selected/);

    my ($sid, $user, $terminal, $program) = unpack('A' . join('A', @cols_size), $line);
    next unless ($sid);

    $program =~ s/\(\w+\)//;

    $data->{$user}->{$program}++;

}

close $file;

foreach my $user (keys %{$data}) {
    foreach my $program (keys %{$data->{$user}}) {
        say sprintf("User = %s %s with program %s", $data->{$user}->{$program}, $user, $program);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i don't understand $counts{$user}{$program}++;